# Trying to change <td> background color based on checkbox value on Razor page

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor-pages, displayfor

I would like this  to turn red whenever the checkbox inside it is checked.
The Html.DisplayFor makes things a little more complicated. The Inactive field in SQL server table is boolean, zero or one.

```
<td align="center">

        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Inactive)

</td>
```

When looking at the table, the value is either 0 or 1. The page shows a checkbox which is desired but I am stuck trying to reference it's value and set the background-color of the surrounding table cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `EditFor` to replace `DisplayFor`,and then add the following js to your view:

```
function changeColor(t) {
            if (t.checked) {
                $(t).parent().css('background', 'red');
            } else {
                $(t).parent().css('background', 'none');
            }
            
        }
        $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            changeColor(this);
        })
$(function () {
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                changeColor(this);
            });
           
        })
```

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. I was able to keep it disabled on regular public view by using Html.DisplayFor instead of .EditFor.
I noticed that it changes the background of all checkboxes that are "true".
Is there anyway to reference just the one "Inactive" checkbox? That way I could use it in other places where Inactive input shares with other checkboxes too.